# Is there a command reverse search in vim?

Tags: vim, search

In linux cli I can do `ctrl-r` and do a reverse search and choose something I have done easily.
Is there something similar in vim? I mean I may run a command using `:` (could be anything like a long substitution) and if I need to do it again I need to retype it.
Is there a way to avoid retyping but instead somehow search back and execute it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may find `q:` useful. It opens the command-line window. The command-line window looks like this:

[image]

I tried to make an animation of its usage:

[image: Animation of q:]

Also see `c_CTRL-F`, which opens the command-line window from command mode.

You can also re-run the last command from normal mode by typing `@:`.

Comment: I wish I could +10, having this feature makes using the vim command mode much nicer. I personally use a few remaps to make it easier to access.

Comment: I wish I could +10 for adding a quick animation.

Answer (score 14):

Entering <kbd>:</kbd> and then the beginning of the command previously issued followed by <kbd>Up</kbd> will retrieve the matching command. If there is more than one option available, you can cycle through them with <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd>.

Comment: Wonderfully useful! TNX 1.0E6